# mod_rewrite does not work correctly

Tags: apache, yii2, centos

Installed yii2 advanced. I can not configure apache on the server. It's worth CentOS. The Apache configuration is below. The main site at: tickets.example.ru And the admin area is here: tickets.example.com/admin

When you log into the admin panel for any link (example '/admin/user/login'), Apache for some reason looks for everything in the frontend. Thinks admin is a controller.

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName tickets.example.ru
ServerAdmin example@example.ru
Alias /admin "/var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/htdocs/backend/web/"
DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/htdocs/frontend/web/"
Options FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /\. - [L,F]
RewriteRule ^/admin$ /admin/ [L,PT]

<Directory /var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/htdocs/frontend/web/>
    AllowOverride none
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/htdocs/backend/web/">
    RewriteEngine on
    AllowOverride none
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/htdocs/phpMyAdmin/">
    RewriteEngine on
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog    /var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/logs/http_error.log
TransferLog /var/www/vhost/tickets.example.ru/logs/http_access.log
```

Comment: why dont you map 2 diff virtual hosts for the app like tickets.ru.com and admin.tickets.ru.com it will make your life easier

Comment: tickets.example.ru and cp.tickets.example.ru ?